# ASP.NET MVC 3. Model contains list<> of objects, pass it to the view, but it returns as NULL back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 3 (APSPxView Engine).

I have a model (MasterModel) which contains some properties. One of them is a list of objects (DetailModels):

```
public class MasterModel
{
    [DisplayName("Master Name")]
    public string MasterName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Master Value")]
    public int? MasterValue { get; set; }

    public List<DetailModel> Details { get; set; }
}

public class DetailModel
{
    [DisplayName("Detail Name")]
    public string DetailName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Detail Value")]
    public int? DetailValue { get; set; }
}
```

So I need to make a view with form on it where I can fill MasterValue property and I want to make a GridView for the Details field and fill DetailValues inside the gridview.

So my controller methods looks so:

```
public ActionResult MasterDetailsView() 
{
    List<DetailModel> details = new List<MasterDetail>
    {
        new DetailModel
        {
            DetailName = "detail0",
        },
        new DetailModel
        {
            DetailName = "detail1",
        },
        new DetailModel
        {
            DetailName = "detail2",
        },
    };

    MasterModel master = new MasterModel
    {
       MasterName = "Master",
       Details = details
    };

    return View("MasterDetailsView", master);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMasterDetailsViewResponseHandler ([ModelBinder(typeof(DevExpressEditorsBinder))] MasterModel model)
    {
        // Some code
    }
```

And finally my view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Main.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyApp.Models.MasterModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<%      
using (Html.BeginForm("MyMasterDetailsViewResponseHandler", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
%>

<%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.MasterName) %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MasterName)%>
<%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.MasterValue) %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MasterValue)%>

//Some code to add Grid view for Details

Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "btnSubmit";
    settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
    settings.Text = "Submit";     
    settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
}).GetHtml();  

<%      
}
%>
</asp:Content>
```

So, my first and main question:
If I submit my form it returns me a model where MasterValue is filled properly but Details property is null. Even if I didn't add GridView just pass Details to the view and submit form back without any Details changes. Details is null anyway. Could you help me to fix my problem, please?

Second question is how to make GridView correctly for the Details where I can fill it and submit everything by one submit button click?

Comment: read up http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx may be you'll find something to figure out a solution

Comment: are you shure that DevExpressEditorsBinder is able to bind complex models? DefaultModelBinder is. It's all about naming the inputs.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. The link in the first comment helps me, now I can pass data and retrieve it back and I understand how to do it. But as I understand, this method means, that I can't make my own UserControl, GridView for example, and each row of grid view is DetailModel, right?

Answer (score 0):

the first issue I see is you are trying to webforms controls within the MVC framework. this doesn't work. (or if it does work, it should be avoided). webforms is a very unique html engine that is tightly integrated within itself.

The "webforms" view engine for MVC is not the same as the Webfroms html engine with server side controls, viewstate, postback, etc.

So there is no GridView or DetailsView controls. You build out the html templates by hand. There isn't any viewstate so anything you want to submit to the server must be rendered on the form. (typically ids as hidden fields, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yep now I feel the difference. Html.EditorFor helps me to understand how it works properly.